# opencv merging multiple namedWindow into one

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, image-processing, trackbar

I currently have multiple separate windows with sliders.Example in the photo below.

[picutre of separate windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBvx2.png)

My question is whether there is a way to have all the separate windows in one large window? Because when the windows are separated it is not clear to me and it is difficult to catch them on the screen.

Here is my code for sliders and namedWindow:

```
#ifndef top_obrada
cv::namedWindow("opcije top", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
int top1 = 0;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina min x", "opcije top", &top1, 100);
int top2 = 9;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina max x", "opcije top", &top2, 200);
int top3 = 0;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina min y", "opcije top", &top3, 100);
int top4 = 108;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina max y", "opcije top", &top4, 500);
int top5 = 0;
cv:: createTrackbar("treshold", "opcije top", &top5, 255);
int top6 = 1;
cv:: createTrackbar("kontrast", "opcije top", &top6, 255);
int top7 = 1;
cv:: createTrackbar("canny", "opcije top", &top7, 255);
int top8 = 0;
cv:: createTrackbar("Operator:\n 0: Opening - 1: Closing  \n 2: Gradient - 3: Top Hat 
                     \n 4: Black Hat", "opcije top", &top8, 4);
int top9 = 1;
cv:: createTrackbar("erode_on", "opcije top", &top9, 1);
int top10 = 1;
cv:: createTrackbar("dilat_on", "opcije top", &top10, 1);
int top11 = 1;
cv:: createTrackbar("morph_size", "opcije top", &top11, 10);


#endif

#ifndef left_obrada_win
cv::namedWindow("opcije left edge", 1);
int left1 = 4;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina min x", "opcije left edge", &left1, 100);
int left2 = 9;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina max x", "opcije left edge", &left2, 200);
int left3 = 1;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina min y", "opcije left edge", &left3, 100);
int left4 = 111;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina max y", "opcije left edge", &left4, 500);
int left5 = 0;
cv:: createTrackbar("treshold", "opcije left edge", &left5, 255);
int left6 = 1;
cv:: createTrackbar("kontrast", "opcije left edge", &left6, 255);
int left7 = 1;
cv:: createTrackbar("canny", "opcije left edge", &left7, 255);
int left8 = 0;
cv:: createTrackbar("Operator:\n 0: Opening - 1: Closing  \n 2: Gradient - 3: Top Hat 
                     \n 4: Black Hat", "opcije left edge", &left8, 4);
int left9 = 1;
cv:: createTrackbar("erode_on", "opcije left edge", &left9, 1);
int left10 = 1;
cv:: createTrackbar("dilat_on", "opcije left edge", &left10, 1);
int left11 = 1;
cv:: createTrackbar("morph_size", "opcije left edge", &left11, 10);

#endif
#ifndef right_obrada_win
cv::namedWindow("opcije right edge", 1);
int right1 = 7;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina min x", "opcije right edge", &right1, 100);
int right2 = 9;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina max x", "opcije right edge", &right2, 200);
int right3 = 10;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina min y", "opcije right edge", &right3, 100);
int right4 = 111;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina max y", "opcije right edge", &right4, 500);
int right5 = 20;
cv:: createTrackbar("treshold", "opcije right edge", &right5, 255);
int right6 = 1;
cv:: createTrackbar("kontrast", "opcije right edge", &right6, 255);

#endif

#ifndef bottom_obrada_win
cv::namedWindow("opcije bottom edge", 1);
int bott1 = 8;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina min x", "opcije bottom edge", &bott1, 100);
int bott2 = 7;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina max x", "opcije bottom edge", &bott2, 200);
int bott3 = 0;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina min y", "opcije bottom edge", &bott3, 100);
int bott4 = 111;
cv:: createTrackbar("pukotina max y", "opcije bottom edge", &bott4, 500);
int bott5 = 255;
cv:: createTrackbar("treshold", "opcije bottom edge", &bott5, 255);
int bott6 = 1;
cv:: createTrackbar("kontrast", "opcije bottom edge", &bott6, 255);
#endif
```

Comment: Combine the images and use a single window

Comment: Or use a gui sdk like Qt